# Trying to set up a CCLabelTTF with an integer as part of it's string in Cocos2d-X C++

Tags: android, c++, string, cocos2d-x, cclabelttf

So in Objective-C with Cocos2d, I'd use a NSMutableString with format to put a variable (score) into a string. I'd take that string and use a CCLabel to place it on the screen.

Using Cocos2D-x, I'm having trouble finding a way to get this result. A simple example would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
int score = 35;
float time = 0.03;
char* name = "Michael";
char text[256];
sprintf(text,"name is %s, time is %.2f, score is %d", name, time, score);
CCLabelTTF* label = CCLabelTTF::labelWithString(text,"Arial",20);
this->addChild(label);
```

Comment: the answer and source code is great, but perhaps i would point out to either go with std::string and its concatenating abilities, or sprintf with char* - mixing both is kind of odd (at least to me).

Comment: yeah true, I edited my answer. but does sprintf accept std::string? I can't remember. coz I personally prefer sprintf than use string to connect all numbers and digits together, just a bit complicated to me.

Comment: You can use the `c_str()` method to convert an `std::string`.

Answer (score 5):

A simpler solution to set the string at any given time ([from here](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/1833)). First define a macro somewhere in your code.

```
#define ccsf(...) CCString::createWithFormat(__VA_ARGS__)->getCString()
```

Then you can change the string any time like this:

```
m_pScoreLabel->setString(ccsf("%d pts", mCurrentScore));
```