# C++ how to add more strings into a method

Tags: c++, xcode, char, cocos2d-x

I have been working in Java since I started programming and decided to learn c++.
What I wrote in Java looked like this:

```
showMessage("Hello world" + randomNumber);
```

And it showed text + integer or float or whatever. But it wont work in c++.
Error message by xCode: `Invalid operands to binary expression ('const char *' and 'float')`

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `sprintf` according to Anton, or to be more `c++`:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "Hello, world " << randomNumber;
showmessage(ss.str());
```

(there's nothing wrong with sprintf, especially if you use `snprintf` instead).

Answer (score 1):

```
    ostringstream os;
    os<<"HelloWorld"<<randomnumber;
    string s;
    s = os.str();
```

string s now contains the string you want as a string object.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) to cast numbers into strings which is fastest method in most cases:

```
showMessage("Hello world" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(randomNumber));
```

showMessage declaration is

```
void showMessage(cosnt std::string& message)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding a new function that is able to convert several types to std::string:

```
template<typename ty>
string to_str(ty t)
{
   stringstream ss; ss << t;
   return ss.str();
}
```

Usage:

```
"Hello World " + to_str(123)
```

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker It won't fail. Concatenating `char*` with `string` is overloaded already in `<string>`

Comment: I thought it's only for `string` being on the left. Maybe I've had this problem with old incomplete implementations, not sure.

Comment: Even through. It won't fail because it will be assigned to a string `string str = "hello World " + to_str(123);`

Answer (score 0):

Define a class `S`. Then write

```
showMessage( S() << "Hello world" << randomNumber );
```

I've coded up the `S` class too many times for SO, and it's a good exercise to create it, hence, not providing the source code.

Note that you can reasonably call it `StringWriter` or something like that, and then just use a `typedef` for more concise code in function calls.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if c-style answer is fine, but I have already answer it here in a cocos2d-x question.

[Trying to set up a CCLabelTTF with an integer as part of it's string in Cocos2d-X C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506187/trying-to-set-up-a-cclabelttf-with-an-integer-as-part-of-its-string-in-cocos2d)

Answer (score 0):

With C++11:

```
showMessage("Hello world" + std::to_string(randomNumber));
```

Answer (score -1):

you should print into the char* instead.

You could do something like

```
char* tempBuffer = new char[256];

sprintf_s(tempBuffer, 256, "Hello world %d", randomNumber);

showMessage(tempBuffer);
```

Comment: `printf` functionality is part of `C` and discouraged in `C++`

Comment: As you can see he used sprintf which is safe

Comment: There is nothing "safe" about `sprintf` in terms of C++. It's part of the whole `printf` family.

Comment: All in all I am not aware of any "good" method in C++ / C. Boost has some nice stuff, but the STL I think does not have something easier than the above.

Comment: There's nothing unsafe about `printf` family, though, isn't `sprintf_s` windows function?

Comment: @AntonRoth, another thing is `%d` — according to error message `randomNumber` is float.

Comment: This will cause memory-leak if invoked repeatedly

Comment: A better choice is `static char buf[256];` - C++ doesn't have a Garbage-Collector (GC)

Comment: A better choice is `std::string` and forgetting that `sprintf` exists.

Comment: There's also an option to use local `char buf[256]` if static is inappropriate. `std::string` is not *always* a better choice and surely unless accompanied with mental damage shouldn't be followed by forgetting that `sprintf` exists. The amount of downvoters is very depressing…

Answer (score -1):

In C++ the standard way to concatenate strings and primitives is to use `stringstream`. Which fulfils the same functionality (and a little bit more) as `StringBuilder` in Java (of course its API differs). However, if you are comfortable using `cout` then you should be fine.

eg.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {
  stringstream ss;
  ss << "Some string - " << 124; // build string    
  string str = ss.str(); // extract string

  cout << str << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Quick reference for stringstream http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/stringstream/