# How to concatenate strings in c++?

Tags: c++, string-concatenation

```
string degreesToDMS(double angle) {
    int intpart = 0;
    int intpart2 = 0;
    int intpart3 = 0;
    return floor(angle) << "\xb0" << modf(angle, &intpart)*60 << "'" << modf(modf(angle, &intpart2), &intpart3)*60 << "\"";
}
```

This function takes in an angle in degrees and outputs a latitude.

I am getting errors on the return statement. How do I properly concatenate different data types to a string in C++?

Comment: Start by creating a string object.

Comment: string::append should help as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ how to add more strings into a method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651817/c-how-to-add-more-strings-into-a-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the streaming operators then use a std::stringstream, like this:-

```
string degreesToDMS(double angle)
{
  int intpart = 0;
  int intpart2 = 0;
  int intpart3 = 0;
  stringstream ss;
  ss << floor(angle) << "\xb0" << modf(angle, &intpart)*60 << "'" << modf(modf(angle, &intpart2), &intpart3)*60 << "\"";
  return ss.str ();
}
```

Comment: ss is allocated on the stack isn't it a problem?

Comment: @0x90 Where else should it be allocated (and why)?

Comment: @0x90 `ss` is allocated on the stack, but the call to `ss.str()` returns an `std::string` object *by value* that is then returned by the function.

Comment: @Prætorian And even if `ss.str()` would return a reference to its internal string the function `degreesToDMS` itself is still declared to return a string by-value.

Comment: After changing each intpart's type to double the above code still does not work. I get a huge error that starts with "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"

Comment: @cRaZiRiCaN: That is a linker error, and each line will tell you what symbol was not found. You need to compile/link the definitions for those symbols into your program.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first build the result in an `std::ostringstream` and then retrieve the string from it.

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << floor(angle) << "\xb0" << modf(angle, &intpart)*60 ...
return ss.str();
```

There are other ways of achieving this result; for instance, with C++11 you can use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to convert the values to `std::string` and then concatenate them together.

```
return std::to_string(floor(angle)) + "\xb0" + 
         std::to_string(modf(angle, &intpart)*60) + ...
```

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate a string in C++ all you need to do is use the `+ operator` on two strings.

If you want to convert a `int` to a `string` use the [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/)

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string firstString = "1st, ";
    string secondString = "2nd ";

    string lastString  = firstString + secondString;

    int myNumber = 3;

    std::stringstream converANumber;
    converANumber << myNumber;

    lastString = lastString + converANumber.str();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string result;
result += std::to_string(floor(angle);
result += "\xb0";
result += std::to_string(modf(angle, &intpart) * 60);
return result;
```

Note that this requires C++11 to get `std::to_string`.